# apache - Object not found only first time

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i configured the apache such a way that the static page should be returned for all the requests. For the first time hit, browser throws the Object not found, but for the subsequent requests, the static page is served. Where&What could be the problem?

Comment: Here is the configuration RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}% !^/static/* [NC] AND RewriteRule ^(.*) /static/welcome.html [NC,R,L].

Comment: I found the root cause. There was an another condition which checks if cookie is present and adds the cookie in the rewrite rule, then stopped further execution of other rules since that rule used L. So mine was not executed. when the next request comes from browser(this time with cookie), my condition and rule got executed and served the static page.